# IIS 7.5 on Win server 2008 r2 useAppPoolCredentials

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to set up Windows authentication for a new website in IIS 7.5.
I have the Windows authentication module enabled for the site and all other authentication types(such as anonymous, Basic etc) disabled.
The App pool for the site runs under a custom identity for which the SPN and host headers have been set appropriately.
On trying to access any content(such as a text file) hosted under the site via the browser, I get a 401.2 error.
I followed [this suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/service-principal-name-spn-checklist-for-kerberos-authentication-with-iis-7-07-5) and added the **useAppPoolCredentials**  attribute to the applicationHost.config and I'm able to access the resource using Windows auth.

I then removed the attribute and saved applicationHost.config again effectively undoing my changes and I'm still able to access the resource.What gives?
Can some one help me understand this behavior?

Also in one particular installation of IIS 7.5 on Win server 2008R2 I have noticed that any changes to the default configuration of a site (or an application) causes IIS to generate a Web.config file automatically at the root of the site/application. Is there a setting to enable this instead of having to update applicationHost.config directly?

**EDIT** The browser was caching the response and hence undoing the changes ans saving the file seemed to make no difference. So the only question I have now is related to generation of the Web.config

Answer (score 4):

With regard to your second question about how to ensure that configuration changes are persisted to a site's `web.config` rather than `applicationHost.config`, this can be controlled via Feature Delegation.

If you navigate to the machine node of IIS Manager you will see an icon named "Feature Delegation":

[image]

Launch this IIS "applet" and you will be presented with a list of features that can have their configuration delegated to `web.config`.

Settings that are marked *Read/Write* will usually have their settings written to the `web.config` file. Settings that are marked *Read Only* will usually have their settings written to `applicationHost.config` and cannot be overridden in the `web.config` file.

As it so happens the `<windowsAuthentication>` configuration can be delegated to the `web.config` file.

**Minor Gotcha:**

Not all of the applets surface the full range of settings you can configure. A good example of this as it so happens is the `<windowsAuthentication>` `useAppPoolCredentials` attribute. It's no-where to be seen in the Authentication applet, not even under *Advanced Settings*.

However you can get at this value (and pretty much everything else) via the *Configuration Editor*. If you navigate to your web site's node in the left hand pane in IIS manager you will see this icon under *Management*:

[image]

If you launch the Configuration Editor you'll be presented with a dropdown list containing a tree of various settings:

[image]

If we select the `/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication` node we are presented with the full spectrum of settings that can be changed. Here we can see the setting we're interested in (`useAppPoolCredentials`):

[image]

You can choose whether to configure the values for the website in `web.config` or in `applicationHost.config` from the *From:* drop down list next to the config section tree drop down:

[image]

If a section has not been delegated as *Read/Write* in the `web.config` then you'll see the following:

[image]

We get an alert saying that this particular feature is locked, all of the settings are greyed out and disabled and there's a padlock indicating that child settings of this feature are also locked out.

Finally, not all settings can be delegated, for example site bindings, application pool, virtual directories.

Comment: Kev: This is excellent. Thanks very much for the detailed walk through and screenshots illustrating how to accomplish this.I just find it a little odd that IIS would not automatically set "useAppPoolCredentials" to true if you enable WindowsAuthentication for an application. It's confusing since a 401.2 does not point you in the right direction as to what is missing. In my opinion this attribute should be set to true by default.